# How does AJAX works with JavaScript & Php? My First Ajax Call getting values However, second call is not

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

I have a piece of work for showing quiz question one by one and While in Number 3 it will say  submit question and calculate all the values. So,
First page I loaded DB table data and saved to session variable. and Displaying questions using one iCounter and Session Values. While pressing button, it calls the quizQuestionNext.php File and shows the value of that from that stage Next button is not working :( .

What I want is :

1. On Page load Fist Question is display
2. On Next Button Click Next Question load and First Question Post values saved
3. And Go on up to 10 or number of questions

Page-1

```
<div align="center" id="qestionDisplayBoard">
*emphasized text*   
<form method='POST' name='quizForm'>
 <table align="center" width='50%' border='0' class='questionDisplay'>
    <input type='hidden' id='<?php echo "qPrimaryKey".$iCount;?>' value='<?php echo $_SESSION[$questionNo][0] ;?>' />

    <tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'><th> Question-<?php echo $iCount." :  ".$_SESSION[$questionNo][1]; ?></th></tr>
    <tr><td><label><input type='radio'  name='<?php echo "Q".$iCount; ?>' value='<?php echo $_SESSION[$questionNo][2];?>'/><?php echo $_SESSION[$questionNo][2]?>  </label></td></tr> 
    <tr><td><label><input type='radio'  name='<?php echo "Q".$iCount; ?>' value='<?php echo $_SESSION[$questionNo][3];?>'/><?php echo $_SESSION[$questionNo][3]?>  </label> </td></tr>
    <tr><td><label><input type='radio'  name='<?php echo "Q".$iCount; ?>' value='<?php echo $_SESSION[$questionNo][4];?>'/><?php echo $_SESSION[$questionNo][4]?>  </label> </td></tr>
    <tr><td><label><input type='radio'  name='<?php echo "Q".$iCount; ?>' value='<?php echo $_SESSION[$questionNo][5];?>'/><?php echo $_SESSION[$questionNo][5]?>  </label> </td></tr>

    <tr><td><input type='hidden' id='<?php echo "participantAns".$iCount; ?>' value='<?php echo $_SESSION[$questionNo][6]?>'/></label> </td></tr>

  </table>
   </form>
  </div>         

    <div align="center"><input class="divButton" type="button" value="| Next Question >>|" id="nextQuestion" onClick="questionDisplay('<?php echo $iCount; ?>')"></input></div>
<div align="center"><input class="divButton hideButton" type="button" value="| SUBMIT QUIZ >>|" id="submitQuiz" onClick="processResult()"></input></div>`
```

Page-2.php

```
    `<?php session_start(); 

header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>';


echo '<response>';

if($_SESSION['noq']<3)
{
    $notEnough="NOt Enought Question";
    echo $notEnough;
}
else
{   
echo "<p>";
    $iCount=$_POST['iCount'];


    echo    $_SESSION['participantQuestionId'][$iCount]     =   $_POST['participantQuestionId'];
    echo "<br/>";
    echo    $_SESSION['participantQuestionResponse'][$iCount] = $_POST['participantQuestionResponse'];
    echo "<br/>";
    echo    $_SESSION['participantActualAnswer'][$iCount]   =   $_POST['participantActualAnswer'];
    echo "<br/>";

    $iCount++;

    echo $questionNo='questionNo'.$iCount;
echo "</p>";    
?>


<form method='POST' name='quizForm'>
 <table align="center" width='50%' border='0' class='questionDisplay'>
    <input type='hidden' name='<?php echo "qPrimaryKey".$iCount;?>' value='<?php echo $_SESSION[$questionNo][0] ;?>' />

    <tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'><th> Question-<?php echo $iCount." :  ".$_SESSION[$questionNo][1]; ?> ?</th></tr>
    <tr><td><label><input type='radio' name='<?php echo "Q".$iCount; ?>' value='<?php echo $_SESSION[$questionNo][2];?>'/><?php echo $_SESSION[$questionNo][2]?>  </label></td></tr> 
    <tr><td><label><input type='radio' name='<?php echo "Q".$iCount; ?>' value='<?php echo $_SESSION[$questionNo][3];?>'/><?php echo $_SESSION[$questionNo][3]?>  </label> </td></tr>
    <tr><td><label><input type='radio' name='<?php echo "Q".$iCount; ?>' value='<?php echo $_SESSION[$questionNo][4];?>'/><?php echo $_SESSION[$questionNo][4]?>  </label> </td></tr>
    <tr><td><label><input type='radio' name='<?php echo "Q".$iCount; ?>' value='<?php echo $_SESSION[$questionNo][5];?>'/><?php echo $_SESSION[$questionNo][5]?>  </label> </td></tr>

    <tr><td><input type='hidden' name='<?php echo "participantAns".$iCount; ?>' value='<?php echo $_SESSION[$questionNo][6]?>'/></label> </td></tr>

  </table>
  </form>`
 `<?php 

if (strpos($_SESSION[$questionNo][0],$_SESSION['quizName']) !== true) 

{unset($_SESSION[$questionNo]);}
}

echo '</response>'; ?>`
```

Page-3.js

```
`function questionDisplay(iCount)
    {   


        qPk="qPrimaryKey"+iCount;
        participantQuestionId = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById(qPk).value);

        qNo="Q"+iCount;

        var pqrArray = document.getElementsByName(qNo);
                for (var x = 0; x < pqrArray.length; x++) 
                {       
                    if (pqrArray[x].checked) 
                    {
                        var participantQuestionResponse = encodeURIComponent(pqrArray[x].value);
                        break;
                    }
                }

        ansNo="participantAns"+iCount;
        participantActualAnswer = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById(ansNo).value);

        if(iCount==3)  //show submit button  if(iCounter==10) 
        {
            document.getElementById("submitQuiz").className = "showButton";
            document.getElementById("nextQuestion").className = "hideButton";
        }
        var allFormValues="iCount="+iCount
                          + "&participantQuestionId="+participantQuestionId
                          + "&participantQuestionResponse="+participantQuestionResponse
                          + "&participantActualAnswer="+participantActualAnswer;

            xmlHttp.open("POST", "quizQuestionNext.php",true);
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=handleServerResponseForQuestionDisplay;
            xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlHttp.send(allFormValues);

    }   

function handleServerResponseForQuestionDisplay()
  {
  if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("qestionDisplayBoard").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
    }
  }`
```

I apologize for such a long post. Please advice any possible solution. Any support is highly appreciated and Thanks in advance

Comment: Any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: The thing is JavaScript works perfectly. However, When I try to Call Next Question Using same function, the Button stays static and No function call !!!